# No me hace bien el UPDATE de descripcion MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, base-de-datos, netbeans

me mandaron un trabajo que hacer y funciona todo correctamente lo que sucede es que en el ´case3´ no se por qué no actualiza bien los datos que le paso y en el phpmyadmin sigue apareciendo en blanco, con todos los demas funciones del menu no me sucede y no me sale ningun tipo error alguien sabria que sucede?

```
menu = scanner.nextInt();
       
       switch(menu){
           
           
           case 1:
               
               stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS superheroe (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(ID),"
               + " nombre VARCHAR(20),"
               + " descripcion VARCHAR(250),"
               + " fuego INT(5),"
               + " agua INT(5),"
               + " viento INT(5))");
               
               break;
               
           case 2:
               
                System.out.println("Ponga el nombre del superheroe");
                nombre = scanner.next();
                stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO SuperHeroe VALUES(null, '" + nombre + "' , 'Descripcion', 0, 0, 0)");
               
               break;
               
           case 3:
               
               System.out.println("Introduza el nombre del superheroe");
               nombre = scanner.next();
               System.out.println("Modificar descripcion");
               descripcion = scanner.nextLine();
               scanner.nextLine();
               stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE SuperHeroe SET descripcion = '"+descripcion+"' WHERE nombre = '"+nombre+"'");
               
               break;
               
           case 4:
               
               System.out.println("Introduza el nombre del superheroe");
               nombre = scanner.next();
               System.out.println("Introduzca del 0 al 5 el nivel de fuego");
               nivelFuego = scanner.nextInt();
               stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE SuperHeroe SET fuego = "+nivelFuego+" WHERE nombre = '"+nombre+"'");
               
               System.out.println("Introduzca del 0 al 5 el nivel de agua");
               nivelAgua = scanner.nextInt();
               stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE SuperHeroe SET agua = "+nivelAgua+" WHERE nombre = '"+nombre+"'");
               
               System.out.println("Introduzca del 0 al 5 el nivel de viento");
               nivelViento = scanner.nextInt();
               stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE SuperHeroe SET viento = "+nivelViento+" WHERE nombre = '"+nombre+"'");
               
               break;
               
           case 5:
               
               System.out.println("Introduza el nombre del superheroe");
               nombre = scanner.next();
               rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM SuperHeroe WHERE nombre = '"+nombre+"' ");
               rs.next();

               do{
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("id") + ": nombre " + 
                    rs.getString("nombre") + "| descripcion " + rs.getString("descripcion") + 
                    "| fuego: " + rs.getString("fuego") + "| agua: " + rs.getString("agua") + 
                    "| viento: " + rs.getString("viento"));
                    System.out.println("");
               }while(rs.next());
               
               break;
```

asi lo tengo antes de ejecutar el case 3
[image: antes]

Asi lo tengo en despues de usar el case 3(puse "soy batman" pero no aparece)

[image: tabla]

en consola uso el caso 1 para crear tabla, el caso 2 inserto a batman pero en el caso 3 que quiero  poner descripcion no hace nada ni salta error lo deja en blanco todavia veis algo raro que haya puesto? necesito que haya espacios, tiene que ser una descripcion breve, en mi caso queria poner soy batman. el caso 4 si funciona bien, me actualiza el nivel de poder correctamente

Comment: Ok, cual caso es entonces el que falla, el 3 ??

Comment: exacto falla el 3

Comment: Revisa que se esté guardando bien el nombre en la variable. si antes tienes un valor, y después ya no tiene nada, significa que estás guardando una cadena vacía. Lo que puedes hacer para comprobar eso puedes imprimir la variable en consola.

Comment: Exacto me guarda la variable en vacio y eso que le meto valores, esto a que se debe?

Comment: Cuando vas a realizar una modificación en tu base de datos siempre haz uso de [TRANSACCIONES](https://www.purocodigo.net/articulo/transacciones-en-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no se por qué no actualiza bien los datos que le paso y en el
> phpmyadmin sigue apareciendo en blanco

La razòn es que la operaciòn `UPDATE` va a actualizar el valor de un registro existente en la base de datos. En este caso no tienes ningùn valor en la tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo si tratas de realizar esta operaciòn indicas que actualice el valor del campo "fuego" cuando el nombre sea "Frany",

```
stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE SuperHeroe SET fuego = 12 WHERE nombre = 'Frany'");
```

si no existe un registro con el nombre "Frany" en la tabla, no se realizarà ninguna operaciòn.

---

En cuanto a que no se actualiza el campo `descripcion` aunque el registro con el nombre existe pero al escribir una descripcion esta no se registra, debes usar `scanner.next()` para obtener el valor de `descripcion` y de esta forma crear correctamente el query ya que usando `scanner.nextLine()` se obtendrà una cadena vacìa y tu campo se actualizarà con este valor incorrectamente, cambia a usar `scanner.next()`:

```
System.out.println("Introduza el nombre del superheroe");
String nombre = scanner.next();
System.out.println("Modificar descripcion");
//String descripcion = scanner.nextLine();
String descripcion = scanner.next();
```

Lo anterior para una palabra pero **si lo que deseas es obtener una frase y almacenarla en la variable descripcion**, define un delimitador que en este caso serìa una nueva linea "\n" usando `scanner.useDelimiter("\n");` esto serìa el còdigo:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.useDelimiter("\n"); //* Delimitador!
System.out.println("Introduza el nombre del superheroe");
String nombre = scanner.next();
System.out.println("Modificar descripcion");
String descripcion = scanner.next();
```

Comment: pero fuego agua y viento me funciona correctamente es con la descripcion que aunque al insertar datos le pongo un texto como "hola" cuando actualizo usando el case3 se me pone sin nada no aparece na es como si se borrara. Con el case 3 me pide el nombre el cual introduzco batman y ya ahi funciona todo pero no se xq en vez de poner el texto que yo quiero poner me lo deja en blanco como en la foto

Comment: ok, el proble es entonces que cuandop actualiza no agrega la descripciòn simplemente la deja con valor vaciò? , Es importante siempre agregar estos detalles cuando se pregunte para dar una mejor soluciòn.

Comment: Exacto, perdona x no dar ese detalle actualice la pregunta con el antes y despues

Comment: Usa un delimitador especificando la nueva linea, ve la actualizaciòn :D

Comment: Perfecto lo del `scanner.useDelimited("\n");` ya me funciona correctamente no sabia que se podia hacer eso en vez de nextLine. Muchas gracias^^

Comment: Excelente FranyXD, saludos!